# Open access Adept-like dataset? (LLM-to-computer-input)

Tags: large-language-models, training-datasets

Here's a demo for [Adept ACT-1 for Transformers](https://www.adept.ai/blog/act-1). I don't doubt that one could create a demo video using zero-shot; actually I tested just now and the basic chat.openai.com interface was able to do some web browsing stuff on the first try if I just prompted it with a list of API methods (e.g. `el.click`) and streamed the DOM to it.

But I assume that, to take their product to the next level, they must be training or fine-tuning on some actual multimodal data, e.g. session recordings labeled with natural language? Am I wrong?

Are there any open-access datasets like this that could be used for open-source models? I'm actually interested in native (e.g. pixel + natural language to game input) more than browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple:

Mind2Web: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.06070.pdf

Webshop: https://webshop-pnlp.github.io/

MiniWoB++: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.11854.pdf

These papers also reference other, similar datasets.